# Post Request Gets "Unable to connect to the remote server" Error

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, request, http-post

First of all this question is not a duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740577/unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server-when-i-call-a-rest-api) because there is no answer in the question, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607302/unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server-error) because I tried all answers.

I created a web service by using ASP.NET Web API 2.0 in .NET 4.5 framework. I send a simple POST request, not a complex carrying binary multipart request.

Service is hosted in `cdn.mydomain.com`

**Failure Story**

When I call the service from `mydomain.com` or `anysubname.mydomain.com` I get the following error:

*Exception Message:* Unable to connect to the remote server

*Inner Exception Message:* A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT:PORT (domain IP address)

**Success Story**

However, when I call the service from Postman, JS, jQuery, local project, otherdomain.com which is hosted by another hosting company, otherdomain2.com which is hosted in VDS works fine and I get result perfectly.

**Calling Service**

I don't thing calling method has an error. It works fine in success story.

```
public Result UploadFile(InputData inputData, string CDNBaseURL, string Token)
{
    Result result = new Result();

    var webClient = new ExtendedWebClient();
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    jss.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

    string url = string.Format("{0}/Service/Upload/File/{1}", CDNBaseURL, Token);

    //  string serializedInputDATA = jss.Serialize(inputData);

    string serializedInputDATA = jss.Serialize(new {
        foo = ""    //  it's just for the test, original is the above
    });

    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}", url), UriKind.Absolute);
        
        string response = webClient.UploadString(uri, "POST", serializedInputDATA);
        result = jss.Deserialize<Result>(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            result.Message += "##" + ex.Message;
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest wr = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        wr.Timeout = 1000 * 30; // timeout in milliseconds (ms)
        return wr;
    }
}
```

I tried so many things, suggestions, this question is my last hope.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

.net 4.5 is no longer supported I would recommend updating to .net 4.5.2 or later.  I would also recommend switch to use the HttpClient instead of WebClient for making rest calls.  But the reason the call is failing is WebClient is not using the right security protocol for the call.  Adding the following line of code before you create the web client should help

```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I tried to set TLS 1.2, it does not work.

Comment: Actually I am using ExtendedWebClient, you can check updated question.

Comment: Now I upgraded .NET version to 4.7.2 both service and caller side, but result is the same

Comment: I would run fiddler or wireshark when making the call with the extended web client.  maybe it will show more information on what is wrong.  Maybe there is a missing header.  Maybe you are calling it http when it should be https or vice versa